# MySQL Docker container - unable to import file

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a Docker container running MariaDB and within the Dockerfile for the image I've copied an SQL file to a location in the container:

```
FROM mariadb

RUN mkdir /adhoc_scripts
COPY bootup.sql /adhoc_scripts
```

Once the container has spun up, I'm able to enter a shell within the container and confirm that the sql file does exist in the specified location:

```
$ docker exec -it my_mariadb_container bash
root@6e3f4b9abe17:/# ls -lt /adhoc_scripts/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1839 Apr 10 18:35 bootup.sql
```

However when I exit the container and try to invoke the following command:

```
docker exec -it my_mariadb_container bash \
        mysql mydb -u root -prootpass \
        < /adhoc_scripts/bootup.sql
```

I get this error:

```
-bash: /adhoc_scripts/bootup.sql: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT1: I tried changing the permissions of `/adhoc-scripts` to 777 as well, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `<` operator operates on the whole `docker exec ...` command instead of the `bash mysql ...` part.

The error message is clear: your bash (outside the container) is trying to interpret the `/adhoc_scripts/bootup.sql` file.

To solve it, try this:

```
docker exec -it my_mariadb_container bash -c "mysql mydb -u root -prootpass < /adhoc_scripts/bootup.sql"
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I knew I was doing something stupid.